# Jquery .addClass() function doesn't work in chrome but it works fine in Mozilla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

i want to add class to my input tag using addClass method in jquery but its not working in chrome !!!

```js
`
    $('#username-signup').blur(function() {

            var tempusername = $('#username-signup').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/identification.php",
                data: { username: tempusername },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(response) {
                    //console.log('success');
                    if (response == 'n') {
                        //console.log('n');
                        $('#username-signup').removeClass('identication-y');
                        $('#username-signup').addClass('identication-n');

                    } else {
                        //console.log('else');
                        $('#username-signup').removeClass('identication-n');
                        $('#username-signup').addClass('identication-y');

                    }
                },
                error: function() {

                    //console.log('error');
                },
                timeout: 5000

            });



        });

//html code :

<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username-signup">



//css :

.identication-n {
    border-color: #ff3547;
}

.identication-y {
    border-color: limegreen;
}



//my php side code :


<?php 
  $x = 'n';
  echo $x;
?>
`
```

---

what is going on ? whats the difference between chrome and mozilla?
i'm also using latest version of "jquery"

---

Comment: What does the HTML for the element with id `username-signup` look like?

Comment: Is `console.log('n')` work in chrome??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  yes console.log('n') works fine

Comment: @devlincarnate at the end of the code i added html codes

Comment: @PHMLa I can't find anything wrong in your code to not work in chrome .. Also if all `console.log`s works in your code the `addClass` should work fine

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thats why im surprised !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as you can see codes are fine so i cleared Browser Data in chrome using link bellow 
and now everything is working, IDK what was the actual problem but here is a solution.

`chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`

clearing last 24 hours was enough for me .

Comment: chek this out ! => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be working fine on Chrome and FF. Maybe you can try a different approach which easier in my opinion than adding and removing class. You could use data-* attributes to achieve what you want.

See this example:

```js
  $('#username-signup').blur(function() {

    var tempusername = $('#username-signup').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      data: {
        username: tempusername
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (typeof response == 'string') {
          $('#username-signup').attr('data-status', 'n');
        } else {
         $('#username-signup').attr('data-status', 'y');

        }
      },
      error: function() {

        //console.log('error');
      },
      timeout: 5000

    });
  });
```

```css
input[data-status='n'] {
  border-color: red;
}

input[data-status='y'] {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username-signup" data-status="">
```

Comment: its a good solution but im wandering why my code is not working in chrome ! im kinda sure something is wrong with my chrome

Comment: Try it on a chrome from a different computer. Or uninstall then install Chrome. Or disable all extensions. Or run Chrome in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something else is causing Chrome to fail before or during the AJAX call and `response` is not being populated or `blur` is not bubbling up. Try the following code and update your post. Also review your Network tab before and after the ajax call to see if maybe you're sending bad data or getting an error in the response from PHP.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#username-signup').blur(function(e) {
    console.log("Username Signup Blue Event");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/identification.php",
      data: {
        username: $('#username-signup').val()
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response == 'n') {
          //console.log('n');
          $('#username-signup').removeClass('identication-y');
          $('#username-signup').addClass('identication-n');
        } else {
          //console.log('else');
          $('#username-signup').removeClass('identication-n');
          $('#username-signup').addClass('identication-y');
        }
      },
      error: function(x, t, err) {
        console.log('Ajax Error:', x, t, err);
      },
      timeout: 5000
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.identication-n {
  border-color: #ff3547;
}

.identication-y {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username-signup">
```

Comment: actually i tried `$('#username-signup').addClass('identication-n');` out of any function even before document.ready! still not working in chrome! the weird thing is that it works fine in mozilla!